# Unit Test Sessions failed to execute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm using VS2015 professional with resharper ultimate and I've started to get the following error in the unit test session window when I'm executing my unit tests.

> 2016.09.21 14:16:54.745   ERROR System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Launch.Stages.DiscoveryStage.Run(CancellationToken token)
>      at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Launch.UnitTestLaunch.RunStage(Object stageObject)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---

tests of other projects works perfectly in VS2013 but not in VS2015.
Yesterday I've installed couple of packages on my pc:
vs14-kb3165756.exe and OpenCover.UI.vsix

I've tried to uninstall the OpenCover package which didn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had same issue, in my case solution configuration was set to "Release". Make sure all your project set to "Debug" and re-try. Worked for me

Comment: I'm also having this issue. All projects are set to Debug, all have "Build" checked in Configuration manager.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone experiencing this issue, after re-adding a UWP Unit Test project multiple times, I found that after I created the new Unit Test Project (Universal Windows), in the Solution's Configuration Manager, for some reason the Build CheckBox was unchecked, and when I checked it, and ran my unit tests, all was executing as expected.

Right Click Solution > Configuration Manager...

Comment: I found this too - crazy. Test runs now. So it seems this error is due to a failure to build, or a failure to build a debug version.

Comment: Checking the build checkbox so that it gets built is what fixed it for me also.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably related `katit`'s answer, but it also happens when the configuration is in Debug Mode, but a deployment using Release version is performed.

Runner fails to run after a deployment (Release) is performed, probably because it tries to run using the latest build output which is composed of Release assemblies (optimized), **so a full rebuild with Debug configuration must be performed.**